# Japanese Text displaying as gibberish when attempting to print lists

Tags: python

I've been attempting to make a tool to help me practice for my up coming speaking test tomorrow for my Japanese class using my meager python skills however when attempting to print any list made of Japanese text it displays gibberish

```
possible_items = ["シャツ １３００円","Tシャツ １３００円"]
print(possible_items)
```

Naturally I'd be expecting that piece of code to print:

```
"["シャツ １３００円","Tシャツ １３００円"]"
```

However it instead ends up spitting out:

```
"['\x83V\x83\x83\x83c \x82P\x82R\x82O\x82O\x89~', 'T\x83V\x83\x83\x83c \x82P\x82R\x82O\x82O\x89~']"
```

Can anybody help me fix this?